# parsing an ini file and storing the values in a hashmap using scanner class

Tags: java, hashmap

i am having a problem with the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileReader("/home/esunmes/NetBeansProjects/random/src/random/something.config"));
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    String line;
    String temp2;
    while (br.hasNextLine()) {
        line = br.next();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("/home/esunmes/NetBeansProjects/random/src/random/inifile.config"));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            temp2 = (String) scan.next();
            if (temp2.equals(line)) {
                Scanner scn = new Scanner(temp2);
                String string;
                while (scn.hasNextLine() && ((string = scn.next()) != "\n")) {
                    String[] temp3 = string.split("//=");
                    if (temp3.length > 1) {
                        String key = temp3[0];
                        String value = temp3[1];
                        map.put(key, value);// TODO code application logic here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Set set = map.entrySet();
    Iterator iter = set.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry maps = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
        String key = (String) maps.getKey();
        String value = (String) maps.getValue();
        System.out.println("key:" + key + " value" + value);
    }
}
```

the two config files are
1.inifile.config

```
 section1
 key1=1
 key2=2

 section2
 key4=4
 key5=5

 section3
 key6=6
 key3=3

 section4
 key7=7

 section5
 key8=8

 section6
 key9=9

 section7
 key10=10

 section8
 key11=11
```

2.something.config

```
 section1
 section2
 section3
 section4
 section8
```

the first config file has sample logs and the second one has the names of the sections to be extracted

the maps should contain the key value pair but they dont
and the maps are coming out to be empty.Can someone please take the time to analyse this ...its really important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- Scanner scn = new Scanner(temp2);

You can simply use scan, which you already created, why you create a new scanner from a String?

- string.split("//=")

It should be `string.split("=")`, you don't need to escape for `"="`, and even if it need escape, it should be `\\` not `//`.

- `hasNext()` should be followed with `next()`, `hasNextLine()` should be followed with `nextLine()`, you should not use `hasNextLine()` then use `next()`.

---

So the code should be

```
Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileReader("file2"));
HashMap map = new HashMap();
String line;
String temp2;
while (br.hasNextLine()) {
    line = br.nextLine();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader("file1"));
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        temp2 = (String) scan.nextLine();
        if (temp2.equals(line)) {
            //Scanner scn = new Scanner(temp2);
            String string;
            while (scan.hasNext() && ((string = scan.next()) != "\n")) {
                String[] temp3 = string.split("=");
                if (temp3.length > 1) {
                    String key = temp3[0];
                    String value = temp3[1];
                    map.put(key, value);// TODO code application logic
                                        // here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Set set = map.entrySet();
Iterator iter = set.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry maps = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
    String key = (String) maps.getKey();
    String value = (String) maps.getValue();
    System.out.println("key:" + key + " value" + value);
}
```